# What is %8F URL encoding character so that stops cut command?

Tags: escape-characters, cut

I am working on URL-escape codes. I have a file named **escapeCodes** which haves all the codes :

```
!   %21     %21
"   %22     %22
#   %23     %23
$   %24     %24
...
~   %7E     %7E
    %7F     %7F
€   %80     %E2%82%AC
    %81     %81
‚   %82     %E2%80%9A
...
    %8D     %C5%8D
Ž   %8E     %C5%BD
    %8F     %8F
    %90     %C2%90
‘   %91     %E2%80%98
’   %92     %E2%80%99
“   %93     %E2%80%9C
```

Third row is not needed, so I used  :

```bsh
cat escapeCodes | cut -d $'\t' -f1,2 > corrected
```

it worked but it does not read all the content;it stopped after **%8F**. Similarly for

```
    %90     %C2%90
    %9D     %9D
    %A0     %C2%A0
­   %AD     %C2%AD
```

URL percent-codes, cut commands stopped. I checked the cut man page [cut man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) but could not find any related option. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: U+008F is [the Single Shift 3 character](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/SS.html), which causes the next character to be interpreted in some other character set, meaning the tab character is no longer a tab. The other characters likely also have behaviours affecting their surroundings, try looking them up.

Comment: It's nothing to do with `bash`. Did you just `cat corrected`? If so, it's your terminal (correctly) interpreting the characters you've sent to it

Comment: @roaima  Would setting `LC_ALL="C"` fix the issue ?

Comment: No. It's characters being interpreted by the terminal. Not bash. Not any shell.